# I can't find cheap miniatures!

Tags: dnd-5e, miniatures

I'm a new dungeon master, and I'm wondering if I should get miniatures and if so where? I have tried some websites but I can't find any creature minis for a reasonable price!

Comment: What cost range do you consider reasonable?

Comment: If you can get 20 rep, you can join the [chat]. Welcome to the site, though! Please take our [tour] to learn more about the questions we do here.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance. Unfortunately, shopping or recommendation questions are off-topic on this site, which is why your question got closed. You can, however, still ask your question in the chat (as mentioned by NautArch) or check out one of [the forums listed here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. The site has addressed this issue in [several questions.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=cheap+miniatures+is%3Aquestion) Thank you for participating and have fun!